I'm trying to use Vuetify 3 with Vue 3 and it's not working very well
I'm studying Vue for a personal project and I'm not able to use Vuetify 3. When I created the project I used Vue Cli, I have Vue 3 and now I'm trying to use Vuetify.
It turns out that after including vuetify 3 the interface actually changed, things like "cyan" colors and structures like v-flex are not working, it's as if vuetify was incomplete.
// main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import 'vuetify/ styles '
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components '
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'
import router from '/router'
import store from './ store'
import { loadFonts } from './plugins/webfontloader'
loadFonts()
const vuetify = new createVuetify({ components, directives })

createApp(App).use(vuetify).use(router).use(store).mount('#app')

no matter where I put the import from
vuetify.min.css does not apply.


<template>
  <v-layout column>
    <v-flex xs6 offset-xs3>
      <div class="white elevation-2">
        <v-toolbar flat dense dark>
          <v-toolbar-title>Register</v-toolbar-title>
        </v-toolbar>
        <div class="p1-4 pr-4 pt-2">
          <input />
          <input
            type="password"
            name="password"
            v-model="password"
            placeholder="password"
          />
          <div v-html="error" />
          <button @click="register">Register</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</template>


Please don't post pictures of code. Copy-paste it here and format it.

<v-flex> is an old Vuetify 2 component.  It's not part of Vuetify 3.  Please make sure you're using the latest version of the documentation while developing.  It probably also explains the problem with your expectation that the CSS look a certain way if you're expecting Vuetify 2 style instead of Vuetify 3.  Clearly CSS is being applied based on the screenshot, with grey background header, and inputs with floating labels.  Unless you added that CSS yourself?

Exact links to the docs you followed are welcome.
